# How to hide a input tag on click out side in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a template in which i want to hide this input tag on clicking out side,
I am opening this input tag onclick of a button and this tag is closing when i click on outside

```
   <input id="phone" *ngIf='student.showinput' type="text" (blur)="showsavephonemodel(student._id,phone.value,student.phone)" #phone [(ngModel)]='student.phone'
      class="phone form-control required email " style="height:38px;">

 onClick(event) {
   if (!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) // or some similar check
      $('#phone').hide();
  }
```

Here the problem is its closing for first time and when i do it for second time i.e clicking outside again,its not closing.Can anyone suggest help please.Thanks.

Comment: instead of using `$('#phone').hide();` you can use variable to manage show-hide  and use it in `*ngIf` on input

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular directives ng-if or ng-hide

```
 <input ng-if='student.showinput' type="text" class="">
```

For example for click event:

hide

```
<button type="button" ng-click="student.showinput = false">click</button>
```

toggle

```
<button type="button" ng-click="student.showinput = !student.showinput">click</button>
```